# Insufficient access on object id

Tags: apex, case

This error is seen by the users on whenever they try to edit a Case record.

Whats puzzling is this error shown to users only for few cases and not all.

Can someone throw me an idea as to where I should be looking ?

Comment: Look in Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings; if Case isn't set to Public Read/Write then the sharing rules lower down in that page may be impacting the access.

Comment: @Keith : You are right..It was indeed the Case Sharing Rules which was the culprit:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this error happen when you've edited the Case, and you click Save?  If so, it's possible that your Case update is causing another object to be updated, (possibly via trigger or workflow), and the user does not have access to that other object.

As the other commenter said, I would start by going to Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles, and looking at the user's profile.  In the "Standard Object Permissions" area, I would double-check the permissions related to Cases.

Next, I would go to Setup -> App Setup -> Customize -> Cases -> Triggers, and make a note of what the triggers on Cases are doing.  Then, it might be good to check out Setup -> Create -> Workflow & Approvals -> Workflow Rules and look at any workflow rules related to cases.  These could help you find other objects that are being updated.  You will then need to make sure that your users have access to these objects.